# optimizing code: fibonacci algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, fibonacci

I'm working on a fibonacci algorithm for really big numbers (100k th number). I need to make this run faster though, but just a couple of seconds and I ran out of ideas. Is there any way to make it faster? Thanks for help.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {


    string elem_major = "1";
    string elem_minor = "0";
    short elem_maj_int;
    short elem_min_int;
    short sum;
    int length = 1;
    int ten = 0;

    int n;
    cin >> n;


    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {

        for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
        {
            elem_maj_int = short(elem_major[j] - 48);
            elem_min_int = short(elem_minor[j] - 48);
            sum = elem_maj_int + elem_min_int + ten;
            ten = 0;
            if (sum > 9)
            {
                sum -= 10;
                ten = 1;
                if (elem_major[j + 1] == NULL)
                {
                    elem_major += "0";
                    elem_minor += "0";
                    length++;
                }
            }
            elem_major[j] = char(sum + 48);
            elem_minor[j] = char(elem_maj_int + 48);
        }
    }

    for (int i = length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        cout << elem_major[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question belongs to [codereview.se]

Comment: Use power of matrix.

Comment: @sam2090 this is the DP approach

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No matter how good optimizations you perform on a given code, without changing the underlying algorithm you can only optimize it marginally. Your approach is with linear complexity and for big values it will quickly become slow. A faster implementation of Fibonacci numbers is by doing matrix [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) on the matrix:

```
0 1
1 1
```

This approach will be with logarithmic complexity which is **asymptotically** better. Perform a few exponentiations of this matrix and you'll notice that the `n + 1`st Fibonacci number is at its lower right corner.

Comment: +1 didn't read through OP's code. Usually `fibonacci` are `recursive` so I thought this might be as well :). Maybe [this](http://fusharblog.com/solving-linear-recurrence-for-programming-contest/) might be useful

Comment: There are some methods that are asymptotically the same as q-matrix method but are faster in practice, for example [http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0020-0190(80)90076-9]. It may be helpful to read papers citing this paper to find other advanced algorithms. Here is my implementation of this algorithm [https://github.com/yuhanlyu/Snippets/blob/master/experiments/fibonacci/fib.c].

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use something like cpp-bigint (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpp-bigint/) for your big numbers.
The code would look like this then

```
#include <iostream>
#include "bigint.h"

using namespace std;
int main() {
    BigInt::Rossi num1(0);
    BigInt::Rossi num2(1);
    BigInt::Rossi num_next(1);

    int n = 100000;

    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
    {
        num_next = num1 + num2;
        num1 = std::move(num2);
        num2 = std::move(num_next);
    }
    cout << num_next.toStrDec() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Quick benchmark on my machine:

```
time ./yourFib
real    0m8.310s
user    0m8.301s
sys 0m0.005s

time ./cppBigIntFib
real    0m2.004s
user    0m1.993s
sys 0m0.006s
```

Answer (score 0):

I would save some precomputed points (especially since you are looking for really big numbers)

ie say I saved 500th and 501st fib number. Then if some one asks me what is 600th fib? I would start computing from 502 rather than from 1. This would really save time.

Now the question how many points you would save and how would select the points to save?

The answer to this question totally depends on the application and probable distribution.